# how to search and replace for multiple value of text file in python?

Tags: python, replace

My data:

```
1 255 59 0 1 255 0 1 1 0 4 0 5 

0 1 255 1 253 0 90 1 1 0 2 0 233
```

I'm new to python and I need to replace all value in text file by 
use conditions:

1. If value in line  = 255, Replace as 1
2. If value in line < 255 (254, 253, 252...), Replace as 0

So, My target data is:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 

0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Actually, I tried to fix it but doesn't work with my data.

This is my code:

```
f1 = open('20130103.txt','r')
f2 = open('20130103_2.txt','w')
count = 255
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('255','1')
    count = count-1
    line = line.replace('%d'%(count), '0')
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

And result is:

```
1 1 59 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 4 0 5 
0 1 1 1 0 0 90 1 1 0 2 0 233
```

Comment: Your conditions are inconsistent with the target data. These conditions are consistent with the data: 
1. If value in line = 1, Keep the value;
2. If value in line = 255, Replace as 1;
3. If value in line < 255 (254, 253, 252...), Replace as 0

Comment: Sorry, In Condition (2) must be ==> < (less than)

Comment: You're still missing the condition "If value in line = 1, Keep the value"

Comment: As for your suggestion, I didn't think of that before...

Answer (score 2):

The eye catcher here is the number `255`, for which you would want to display `1`, which clearly indicates, you are only interested in the `8th bi`t.
The only case which looks strange is how your o/p not conforming with your requirement, does not manipulate `1` in which case, you have to leave it out of your transformation

If I have to trust your requirement

```
>>> with open("test.in") as fin, open("test.out","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        line = (e >> 7 for e in map(int, line.split()))
        fout.write(''.join(map(str, line)))
        fout.write('\n')
```

If I have to trust your data

```
>>> with open("test.in") as fin, open("test.out","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        line = (e >> 7 if e != 1  else 1 for e in map(int, line.split()))
        fout.write(''.join(map(str, line)))
        fout.write('\n')
```

Another alternate view to this problem.

```
>>> with open("test.in") as fin, open("test.out","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        line = (e / 255 if e != 1  else 1 for e in map(int, line.split()))
        fout.write(''.join(map(str, line)))
        fout.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
with open('20130103.txt', 'r') as f1, open('20130103_2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        values = line.split()
        new_values = ' '.join('1' if value == '255' else '0' for value in values)

        f2.write(new_values + '\n')
```

- `line.split()` splits the line into chunks. `'a    b'.split() == ['a', 'b']`
- `'1' if value == '255' else '0' for value in values` is a generator that just outputs `'1'` or `'0'`, depending on the value of an item in your list of values.
- `' '.join()` joins together the values in the list (or generator, in this case) with a space.

Comment: It seems like the OP wants 1 to be left alone for some reason, at least if we trust the target data..

Comment: You've got twice `open as f1`, you might wanna change the latter to `f2` :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can pass `re.sub` a function -- instead of a replace string -- to gain really fine control over how replacements are done:

```
import re
lines = ['1 255 59 0 1 255 0 1 1 0 4 0 5',
     '0 1 255 1 253 0 90 1 1 0 2 0 233']
def do_replace(match):
    number = int(match.group(0))
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return str(number)
    elif number == 255:
        return '1'
    elif number < 255:
        return '0'
    else:
        raise ValueError
for line in lines:
    print re.sub(r'\d+', do_replace, line)
```

prints:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```